# Verifying and Limiting User Access to Certain Entities - Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

What is considered best practice in an asp.net MVC application using Identity that is shared between many users, each of which has their own sets of records / accounts, and any given user should not be able to access anything but their own records?

I.e. if **user 1** browses to the url `gadgets/details/10`, which returns a View with records that user 1 created and should have access to, where `10` is the Id of the record/Model, and user 1 inadvertently tried to browse to `gadgets/details/11` where the record with Id `11` is owned by **user 2.**

Other than traversing the database relationships from gadgets all the way up to whatever entity is associated with a user account (i.e. Gadgets has a foreign key to GadgetCategories, GadgetCategories has a foreign key to Stores, and users have foreign keys to Stores, where they could then be compared using the properties of user from HttpContext and OwinContext for the user), is there way of confirming a user is accessing records they should have access to, and denying any requests they shouldn't have access to?

What is considered best practice for these situations?

Comment: You need to validate that in the controller method, and if the current user does not have access to those records, return an error code

Comment: So essentially by using something like the example I gave where you need to traverse up the model hierarchy using foreign keys?

Comment: Yes (unless your `Gadgets` table contains a field for the user id)

Comment: Are there any solutions where we could avoid having to make these database calls each time a new Controller method is called? In some cases there may be a simple model with a few properties to display, but it's a child of a child of a child of a child..... etc., and all of the database calls necessary to get to the point where the Store and user foreign keys can be compared (in the example given) to confirm a user has access to whatever is being requested, feel excessive. Is there any way to incorporate `Session` data into the architecture for this purpose, where the `Session` object might...

Comment: ...be populated on an initial server request by any given user, before accessing any Controller methods that make database calls and return Views?

Comment: Why do you think you need multiple database calls? Just use a single query with joins to get the data from the `Gadgets` table you need in the view plus the user ID from the `Stores` table

Comment: You are right, but I am mainly asking if there's some other way to look at this problem of needing to protect other users/accounts data in a shared database, like some other best practice or an alternative architectural approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132859/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-amartin).